# Is there any heuristic to polygonize a closed 2D raster shape with n triangles?

Tags: 2d, rendering, rasterization

Let's say we have a 2D image black on white that shows a closed geometric shape.

Is there any (not naive brute force) algorithm that approximates that shape as closely as possible with n triangles? If you want a formal definition:

> Approximate the shape with a polygon that when rendered into a new 2D
>   image will match the largest number of pixels possible with the
>   original image.

Comment: Have you tried [link](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/)?

Comment: @AranHase This is good for my other question. Here I get a raster as input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for approximating sihlouette image as polygon](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40456/algorithm-for-approximating-sihlouette-image-as-polygon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to do it in two or three steps:

For converting a raster image to polygons you can use pre-existing software like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace

Optimizing the result from that to get the best possible result with a specific number of polygons I believe is much harder. However efficiently optimizing an existing mesh down to a lower poly count isn't too difficult if you don't care about the result being optimal. For example http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/proj/meshopt/ describes one algorithm to optimize a 3D mesh, based on a parameter saying how much to optimize it.

Once you have that optimized mesh you could apply a [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) algorithm to the vertex positions to try to further improve the fit.