# Algorithm for approximating sihlouette image as polygon

Tags: textures, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any heuristic to polygonize a closed 2D raster shape with n triangles?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40398/is-there-any-heuristic-to-polygonize-a-closed-2d-raster-shape-with-n-triangles)

I want to be able to analyze a texture in real time and approximate a polygon to represent a silhouette.  Imagine a person standing in front of a green screen and I want to approximately trace around their outline and get a 2D polygon as the result.  Are there algorithms to do this and are they fast enough to work frame-to-frame in a game?

(I have found algorithms to triangulate polygons, but I am having trouble knowing what to search for that describes my goal.)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the DetectVertices function [here](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/99885#1636179). Its pretty good I've used it quite a bit myself.